# React Get Fetch unique key value object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
{
    "-ABCSNNIAVLxUU3fkeW6x": {
        "content": "Lorem ipsum",
        "title": "Heading 1",
    },
    "-ABWQKtx55X6z5KCCAw": {
        "content": "Lorem ipsum lorem",
        "title": "Heading 2",
    }
}
```

When I make a GET request I have a JSON output like above. The output key part in the form of key, value object has a **unique id**. How can I do fetch get request process in React native?

I learned to do it with object.keys(res), but I couldn't do how to list it. My goal is to do setData and list it with FlatList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object.values(res).map(object => object)
```

This way I solved my problem.